# No Unity launcher

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have Ubuntu 12.04 and was trying to install updates.  Big mistake because the next thing I know I just have a blank wallpaper screen and nothing else.  I've tried every piece of advice given on various post (unity --reset, ccsm) nothing works.  Also, none of my USB ports are working either and seriously have no idea what that's all about.

Comment: Which graphics card are you using? Is it an ATI card?

Comment: I have no idea.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an nvidia video card?  Run the "additional drivers" tool and install the "nvidia_experimental_310" driver.  This will fix the problem with the left edge not triggering the launcher.

Comment: The window won't even open.

Comment: Which "window"?  Please describe in further detail; I can't help you much otherwise.

Comment: I do have a nvidia video card and can open the all settings window, click on them, and have them open except for the additional drivers.  That won't launch and my mouse flickers everytime I glide over it.

Comment: Try uninstalling and reinstalling Additional Drivers from Software Center.

I am noticing that "Additional Drivers" won't appear in 12.10 once I undock its icon from the launcher.  Definitely deserves to be reported as a bug, if it hasn't already.

Comment: Is there a keyboard command for Software center but I don't know how to get to it otherwise.

Comment: Hit the "Windows" key on your keyboard, this will show the launcher, which by default, has a software center icon.  EDIT:  Reported this on Launchpad as bug #1143008.

Comment: That key isn't working for me either.  It's like my keyboard has turned against me as well.  I am really appreciating the help and was wondering if we could move this over to chat as to avoid extended discussions in comments.